# Which tezos-client commands reveal the public key?

Tags: tezos-client, reveal, revelation, public-key

I know that the `tezos-client reveal key for <src>` command reveals the public key for the `<src>` address. What other tezos-client commands also reveal the public key?

Edit: I mean, specifically reveal the public key on the chain.

Comment: Do you mean specifically send a reveal operation to the chain, or reveal to the user in general?

Comment: I mean, reveal to the chain.

Answer (score 6):

The publicKey must be revealed before the wallet can inject an operation to the blockchain. The client (and most wallets) will automatically add a reveal operation onto the first operation you try to perform with the new address. E.g. sending xtz or an fa1.2/fa2 token, delegating to a baker or originating a contract, will all trigger a reveal operation first